# Flutter Project - iOS with XCode doesn't work correctly

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I have a flutter project and I'm writing native code for a third party sdk integration.
Today, i have open the xCode but i only see Pods folder in project navigator. Yesterday there was a Runner folder too and I was writing the native code in  this folder.

I have created a new empty flutter project and when i click the open with xCode in VsCode, this project is opening correctly in xCode, i can see both Pods folder and Runner folder.

What should I do to solve this problem?